# Backed-up database using codeigniter, doesnt put quote to insert values (syntax error)

Tags: php, mysql

I creating a backup and restore feature for my website and I am using codeigniter as my framework. When I use the dbutil of the framework the backed up file doesnt quote insert values, this is causing an error when I import the sql file to my database because of syntax error.

```
INSERT INTO `account_client` 
    (`IdClient`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Contact`, `Email`, 
    `Username`, `Password`, `Profile`, `DateMod`, `Status`, 
    `suspend_from`, `suspend_to`, `suspend_day`) 
VALUES (8, Remuel, Sigua, 03222212121, remuelsigua@gmail.com, 
        Rem21, $2y$10$hPb/gA6Pyy/6IWO87gJfi.4UIh8pB/GZdBVHxFHahI/fcfwrYUkx6, 
        NULL, 2018-11-17 17:01:06, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please put your string values within '',like below

```
INSERT INTO `account_client` 
        (`IdClient`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Contact`, `Email`, 
        `Username`, `Password`, `Profile`, `DateMod`, `Status`, 
        `suspend_from`, `suspend_to`, `suspend_day`) 
VALUES (8, 'Remuel', 'Sigua', 03222212121, 'remuelsigua@gmail.com', 
        'Rem21, '$2y$10$hPb/gA6Pyy/6IWO87gJfi.4UIh8pB/GZdBVHxFHahI/fcfwrYUkx6', 
        NULL, '2018-11-17 17:01:06', 1, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: That is the problem, I cant put quote every now and then when I backup my database. That is why I am asking why codeigniter dbutil backup work this way.